# Difference between as.integer and parse_integer

Tags: r, readr

I have a question regarding the difference between `as.integer` and `parse_integer`. Anyone can explain for me? Thank you!

Comment: `as.integer` is for coercing non-integers to integers. You can coerce floats, logical, or characters to integers using `as.integer`. `parse_integer` is to parse integers from character.

Comment: But in this case it is similar `a <- parse_integer(c("1", "2", "3"))` `b <- c("1", "2", "3")
as.integer(b)` isn't it?

Comment: In that case, you could use either. But they are intended for different purposes and are not always interchangeable.

Comment: Didn't really find any example differentiating between `as.integer` and `parse_integer` but `parse_number` and `as.numeric` works very differently `readr::parse_number(c('1a', '2b', '3', 'a3.1453'))`, `as.numeric(c('1a', '2b', '3', 'a3.1453'))`. I would expect `readr::parse_integer(c('1a', '2b', '3'))` to return 1, 2 and 3 but it does not.